# SoapClient not showing XML request

Tags: php, xml, soap

I need to see the XML I am sending a web service to make sure its correct but I cant get the `__getLastRequest()` function to work. I know it hits the server because I dumped the methods I am supposed to use. Anyone see anything?

```
try
{
    $soapclient = new SoapClient('http://freight.onestopshipping.com/GTSService/services/GTSWebServiceAutoQuotes?wsdl', array('trace' => TRUE ) );


    $params = array(

      'RaterRequestAutoQuotes' => array(
            'userName' => 'XXXXX',
            'password' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
            'pickupDate' => '05/29/2017',
            'deliveryDate' => '06/20/2017',
            'destZipCode' => '83814',
            'origZipCode' => '15065',
            'RaterRequestItems' => array(
                  'item_class' => '85',
                  'nmfc' => '?',
                  'weight' => 100,
            ),
      ),

    );

    $response = $soapclient->getRate($params);

    //var_dump($response);

    echo "REQUEST:\n" . $soapclient->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
    // do some service level error stuff
        echo $e;
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // do some application level error stuff
        echo $e;
}
```

The XML Reqeust example they sent looked like:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://services.gts" xmlns:xsd="http://services.gts/xsd">

   <soap:Header/>

   <soap:Body>

      <ser:getRate>

         <!--Optional:-->

         <ser:rRequest>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:deliveryDate>05/29/2017</xsd:deliveryDate>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:destZipCode>83814</xsd:destZipCode>

            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->

            <xsd:items>

               <!--Optional:-->

               <xsd:item_class>85</xsd:item_class>

               <!--Optional:-->

               <xsd:nmfc>?</xsd:nmfc>

               <!--Optional:-->

               <xsd:weight>100</xsd:weight>

            </xsd:items>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:origZipCode>15065-1840</xsd:origZipCode>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:password>XXXXXXXXXX</xsd:password>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:pickupDate>05/19/2017</xsd:pickupDate>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:userName>XXXXXX</xsd:userName>

         </ser:rRequest>

      </ser:getRate>

   </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trace request messages, you can use build-in `TCP/IP monitor` tool of Eclipse IDE (More Info: [How to trace SOAP message in Eclipse IDE](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/how-to-trace-soap-message-in-eclipse-ide/)). Or for more about functional testing purpose, try [SoapUI | Functional Testing for SOAP and REST APIs](https://www.soapui.org).